# argument is missing, with no default, but only in loop

Tags: r, loops

I wrote couple of simple custom functions in purpose to consolidate them in one specific function.

Those are used to subset data. First is less specific:

```
unspecific_subsetting=function(x,var1,var2){
  subset(x, x$COL1 %in% var1 
         & x$COL2 %in% var2
         & x$COL3 %in% "A")
}
```

In `x$COL3` I put `"A"` because it is constant. Second is more specific, it does exactly same thing but it subsets only a chosen row:

```
specific_subsetting=function(x,var1,var2,year){
  subset(x, x$COL1 %in% var1  
         & x$COL2 %in% var2
         & x$COL3 %in% "A"
         & x$COL4 %in% (year+1))
}
```

I wrote `(year+1)` but later on I might change it to variable as well. The last function I use is simple percent change:

```
pcchange=function(x){  c( NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)] ) }
```

So at this point it is about time to explain - I wish to combine all those functions into one convenient function, which calculates percentage change of certain substracted dataset and then returns pcchange value from chose row. It looks like this:

```
big_function=function(x,var1,var2,year){
  x=unspecific_subsetting(x, var1, var2)
  x=data.frame(x,"growth"=(pcchange(x$COLn)*100))
  x=getforecast(x,var1,var2,year)}
```

To be more specific - it basically subset certain part of data, then calculates and adds new column with pcchanges to df, and finally return desired row. This function WORKS. And works like a charm. The problem starts when i put it into loop. So far i write loops based on lists so it looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(df.names.list)){
assign(NEW.df.names.list[i],big_function(get(df.names.list[i])),var1,var2,year.list[i])}
```

So as you can see I am trying to create new dfs with each one consisting only selected row (BTW: I am aware my "subset" functions overlaps in `big_function` but I dont mind that). And this returns me an error:

```
  Error in unspecific_subsetting(x, var1, var2) : 
  argument "var1" is missing, with no default
```

I checked, this problem consider every single argument in every function, it only returned first one R stumbled upon.
I have literally no clue what is the issue here, I used similar loop couple of times and never had result like this.

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: first thing to check: what do you have in `var1` when the error occurs ?

Comment: I use "Answer Your Question" to make post easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce error on test data. My test df look like this:

```
COL1    COL2        COL3    COL4    COLn
CarBrand1   Gas        A    2014    5.34
CarBrand1   Gas        A    2010    1.46
CarBrand1   Gas        A    2007    1.18
CarBrand1   Diesel     A    2006    1.27
CarBrand1   Electric   A    2013    1.78
CarBrand1   Electric    A   2001    1.44
CarBrand2   Electric    A   2007    1.39
CarBrand2   Diesel      A   2004    1.04
CarBrand2   Gas         A   2009    1.89
CarBrand2   Gas         A   2004    1.83
CarBrand2   Electric    A   2000    1.69
CarBrand2   Electric    A   2001    1.61
CarBrand2   Electric    A   2013    1.29
CarBrand2   Diesel      A   2001    2.00
CarBrand2   Diesel      A   2006    1.78
CarBrand2   Gas         A   2010    1.10
CarBrand2   Gas         A   2002    1.51
CarBrand2   Gas         A   2012    1.78
CarBrand2   Electric    A   2009    1.84
CarBrand3   Gas         A   2013    1.24
CarBrand3   Gas         A   2009    1.98
CarBrand3   Gas         A   2015    1.91
CarBrand3   Gas         A   2007    1.14
CarBrand3   Diesel      A   2000    1.54
CarBrand3   Diesel      A   2013    1.60
```

First two columns are car brand and engine type, third is some constant fourth is year and last is some random value. I put into R my custom functions exactly as in first post so my test code looks like this:

```
newdf=0
output=0
NEW.df.names.list=c("output")
df.names.list=c("mydf")
year.list=2012
for (i in 1:length(df.names.list)){
  assign(NEW.df.names.list[i],big_function(get(df.names.list[i])),"CarBrand3","Diesel",year.list[i])}
```

I work on multiple dfs, this only makes on loop but it gives me exactly same error. I know this is not exactly answering my own question, its more like extension...